# I can not use feature.get Geometry () in a MultiLineString

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I'm plotting GeoJSON on my map using google maps api v3. With the point of layers it is functioning normally. But I have a MultiLineString Camda and center the map on the geometry gives an error.This also occurs with a polygon, but with the points works well. Is there any other way to centralize to MultiLineString and Polygons?

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(cicloviasLayer, 'addfeature', function (e) {
     console.log(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()); // MultiLineString Ok!
     map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().get());

  });
```

Erro:

```
e.feature.getGeometry(...).get is not a function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Data.MultiLineString](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.MultiLineString) class doesn't have a `get` method, it has a `getAt` and `getArray` methods.

> getAt(n:number)
>
> Return Value:  Data.LineString
>
> Returns the n-th contained Data.LineString.

The returned LineString has a `getAt` method that returns a `google.maps.LatLng` object

> getAt(n:number)
>
> Return Value:  LatLng
>
> Returns the n-th contained LatLng.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cicloviasLayer, 'addfeature', function (e) {
  console.log(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()); // MultiLineString Ok!
  // will center the map on the first vertex of the first LineString
  map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().getAt(0).getAt(0));
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/somy6c7a/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map, red "measle" on point]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137
    },
  });
  map.data.setStyle({
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 4,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.data, 'addfeature', function(e) {
    console.log(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()); // MultiLineString Ok!
    // will center the map on the first vertex of the first LineString
    map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().getAt(0).getAt(0));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.feature.getGeometry().getAt(0).getAt(0),
      map: map,
      icon: {
        url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
        size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
      }
    })
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson({
    "type": "Feature",
    geometry: {
      "type": "MultiLineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-105.021443,
            39.578057
          ],
          [-105.021507,
            39.577809
          ],
          [-105.021572,
            39.577495
          ],
          [-105.021572,
            39.577164
          ],
          [-105.021572,
            39.577032
          ],
          [-105.021529,
            39.576784
          ]
        ],
        [
          [-105.019898,
            39.574997
          ],
          [-105.019598,
            39.574898
          ],
          [-105.019061,
            39.574782
          ]
        ],
        [
          [-105.017173,
            39.574402
          ],
          [-105.01698,
            39.574385
          ],
          [-105.016636,
            39.574385
          ],
          [-105.016508,
            39.574402
          ],
          [-105.01595,
            39.57427
          ]
        ],
        [
          [-105.014276,
            39.573972
          ],
          [-105.014126,
            39.574038
          ],
          [-105.013825,
            39.57417
          ],
          [-105.01331,
            39.574452
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```